# Dynamic Action In ORACLE APEX - Populating a Field from Form on Page 2 using data entered into Field from Form on Page 1

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-apex

I have 2 pages, containing 1 Form Each (Page 1 has ACCOUNT INFORMATION, Page 2 has CARD INFORMATION) in an Oracle Apex Application I'm building.

When the user enters their ***Account Number*** in the **ACCOUNT INFORMATION form**, in Field **P1_ACCOUNT_NUM** and they save their entry, THEN the same ***Account Number*** must be Auto Populated into the **CARD INFORMATION form** in Field **P2_AID** *(This page item is used as a Foreign Key coming from ACCOUNT INFORMATION)*

I would like to have this accomplished using a Dynamic Action OR, if deemed easier, using a Process.

Note: Both forms are triggered by a CREATE button. Both forms are based off of Tables from a DATABASE bearing similar name.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usual way to do that is to

- create P1_ACCOUNT_NUM
- create P1_BTN button which **redirects to page in this application**

  - target is page 2
  - in link properties, set P1_ACCOUNT_NUM item as a "source" and P2_AID as a "target" item
- run the form
- populate P1_ACCOUNT_NUM
- when you press the button, Apex will redirect you to page 2 and P2_AID will have value you entered into P1_ACCOUNT_NUM

---

Whichever way you choose to navigate from one page to another, you should use any available option to pass values between those pages. **Link** is the most usual way:

- you can create it as a button (as in my example). Or,
- create it *dynamically* in e.g. Interactive Report source query, utilizing [APEX_PAGE.GET_URL](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/apex/22.1/aeapi/GET_URL-Function.html#GUID-83A2A2A0-5B43-4A3E-BBD3-2FBD3B7B01CE) function.

As usual, there's more than one way to do that.

Comment: Okay that option worked. Here's the new issue. I have 5 forms (inclusive of the two above) PERSONAL INFORMATION, EMPLOYMENT INFORMATION and ONLINE INFORMATION.

PERSONAL INFORMATION is the main page and the other 4 forms are opened using the CREATE Button that opens Modal Dialogs. When I click on CREATE for CARD INFORMATION I want to populate the P2_AID field with the same Account number coming from ACCOUNT_NUM in ACCOUNT INFORMATION. 

This is not working.

Comment: To clarify, the solution you gave works with just the two tables I initially have. But when the other tables are added I'm getting an Primary Key Error. So I need to same solution to work under this new circumstance. Let me know if you require more details.

Comment: If you have to **share** the same value all over the application, go to **Shared components** and create an **application item** (name it e.g. APP_ACCOUNT_NUM). Set its value on the **first** form you use, i.e. the one that initially creates that value. Then reference it on all other forms. Though: note that - from the Stack Overflow perspective - this is a new problem which requires a new question to be asked. I don't care much about that, just beware that some other community members might complain about it.

Comment: Thank you for the response and the note, I also thought that it might be a new problem I'm talking about even though it's one thing in my head.

Comment: Seemingly encountered an issue with the solution. I created the Application Item, but I can't seem to find the avenue to apply a value to the said item to be able to use it accordingly. Is there something i'm missing?

Comment: Did you try to do that with a dynamic action? Or even process with fires on submit?